# How to convert for loop matrix multiplication using Eigen C++: incorrect results

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I have the following for loop that works:

```
    static const int ny = 10; 
    std::vector<double> ygl(ny+1);

    double *dVGL; 
    dVGL = (double*) fftw_malloc(((ny+1)*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
    memset(dVGL, 42, ((ny+1)*(ny+1))* sizeof(double));
    double *dummy1; 
    dummy1 = (double*) fftw_malloc(((ny+1)*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
    memset(dummy1, 42, ((ny+1)*(ny+1))* sizeof(double));

    double *dummy2; 
    dummy2 = (double*) fftw_malloc(((ny+1)*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
    memset(dummy2, 42, ((ny+1)*(ny+1))* sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < ny+1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ny+1; j++){
            ygl[j] = -1. * cos(((j) * EIGEN_PI )/ny);
            dummy1[j + ny*i] =  1./(sqrt(1-pow(ygl[j],2))); 
            dummy2[j + ny*i] = 1. * (i);
            dVGL[j + ny*i] =  dummy1[j + ny*i] * sin(acos(ygl[j]) * (i)) * dummy2[j + ny*i];
        
        }
    }
```

The above works fine, now I convert to Eigen and I am getting off results:

```
    Eigen::Matrix< double, 1, ny+1> v1; 
    v1.setZero();
    std::iota(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0);

    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, ny+1> dummy1; 
    dummy1.setZero();

    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, ny+1> dummy2; 
    dummy2.setZero();

for (int j = 0; j < ny+1; j++){
            v[j] = 1./(sqrt(1-pow(ygl[j],2)));
    }
    dummy1 = v.array().matrix().asDiagonal(); //this is correct
    dummy2 = v1.array().matrix().asDiagonal(); //this is correct

    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, ny+1> dVGL; 
    dVGL.setZero();
for (int i = 0; i < ny+1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ny+1; j++){
            ygl[j] = -1. * cos(((j) * EIGEN_PI )/ny);
            dVGL(j + ny*i) =   sin(acos(ygl[j]) * (i)); //this is correct
        }
    }
//##################################
dv1 = (dummy1) * (dVGL) * (dummy2); //this is incorrect, dVGL outside for loop is different from inside for loop!!
```

I have been wracking my brain for a week now over this I cannot seem to fix it. why is `dVGL` out side the for loop is different?? (off as if my rows and columns have length ny+1, but When I flatten my array I am using just ny.) why is that?

I feel like this should be a simple issue.

Comment: i do not know eigen but shouldnt there be 2 indexes in to dvgl here `dVGL(j + ny*i) =   sin...`

Comment: Just replacing the raw pointers in the first (working) example leads to this output: https://godbolt.org/z/jr8dcTEh5 Is that really what you want? (It includes inf and NaN results)

Comment: And in your Eigen port you use `ygl[i]` before it is initialized (or it is not part of the code you shared). Are you sure your intermediate results are correct? (Did you output them?) To get element-wise products in the last line, you need to write `dv1 = dummy1.array() * dVGL.array() * dummy2.array()` (or declare your variables as `Eigen::Array<...>` instead of `Eigen::Matrix<...>`).

Comment: Actually, I just noticed you are accessing your `(ny+1) * (ny+1)`-sized matrices with index `j + ny*i`. Do you mean `j + (ny+1)*i` instead?

Comment: @pm100 `dVGL(j+ny*i)` would be equivalent to `dVGL(j, i)` if the matrix had `ny` rows. As it is written it actually points to `dVGL(j-i, i)` (for `j>=i`) or `dVGL(j-i + ny+1, i-1)` if `j<i`. Essentially, it just does `dVGL.data()[j+ny*i]`

Comment: @chtz thanks for the response, it seems that when I changed my indexing to (i,j) and/or (j+(ny+1)*i) like you suggested, it works and returns the correct output!!

Comment: Are you still interested how to write your expression without a loop? If so, [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: @chtz I didn't think it was possible to get rid off the for loop for functions like acos/pow since it might not be an acos function overloaded for matrices. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Most element-wise functions should be overloaded or exist as methods. But you need to work in the `Array`-domain, i.e., either `ygl.array().acos()` or `acos(ygl.array())`.

Comment: And instead of `pow(...,2)` better use `.abs2()` or `.square()`.

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking for a function like ``.square()``and I know this is not related to my question here but do you know how the matrix division is done in Eigen?. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chtz in the comments, I was able to fix this problem simply by changing my indexing:

```
dVGL(j + (ny+1)*i) =   sin(acos(ygl[j]) * (i)); 
dv1 = (dummy1) * (dVGL) * (dummy2); //Then this is correct
```